# move C++ object to memory location

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I probably will need to do something similar to what std::vector doing:

```
T *mem = malloc(...); // notice this is just memory allocation.
T t;
move... t to mem
mem->doSomething();
```

How I can move `t` over allocated memory?

How can I move object from allocated memory onto new variable.

How can I delete object from allocated memory - call d-tor manually?

Must I use placement new and assignment operators?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do that?

Comment: yea what are you actually trying to do....

Comment: refactoring something from C. It is something very similar to std::vector. Currently have pointers to Objects, but I want to "put" objects inside the "array". Suppose you need to insert in the middle, at the moment I memmove lots of pointers and insert new pointer in the "hole".

Comment: Use a copy contructor...

Comment: Are you looking for [placement new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new)?

Comment: I am exploring possibilities for optimisation. Pls don't tell me to use std::vector :)

Comment: Allocate your objects using `new`, then put the pointer inside the array (if you know what you are doing and casting always correct, you can even use void pointers to store whatever object you want)

Comment: @Michael - well not sure how it will be faster. I could do a new object with placement new and copy c-tor. but is there other better way?

Comment: @Nidhoegger - this is what I already have. But I ant to remove pointers and put actual objects into the array.

Comment: @Nick: Is `T` a class of your own? If so, you could define a custom allocator for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, but if you don't know what you're doing then I would avoid doing this:

```
#include <new>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* mem = malloc(sizeof(T));
T t;
T* tt = new(mem) T( std::move(t) );
tt->doSomething();
tt->~T();
free(mem);
```

You can't literally "move" `t` to that memory, `t` will always be where it was created, but you can create another object at that location, as a copy of `t` (using a move constructor to make the copy if it has one, but that still leaves `t` where it was and still existing).

Comment: Still existing, but possibly empty.

Comment: Excellent, can you just include the code how to move tt over t , e.g. memory over normal variable.

Comment: @Nick, `t = tt`. if you mean something else you'll have to explain what you mean. I have no idea what "move memory over a variable" means.

Comment: @nwp yeah for some value of empty :)

Comment: @JonathanWakely - move object pointed by tt to local variable, so I do not need to call destructor manually. does T t2 = std::move(*tt) will work ?

Comment: @Nick No. You should still destroy `tt` if you don't like leaks. You can skip it if you can guarantee that the destructor is a noop after `T` has been moved from, but that is very fragile code.

Comment: Let me summarize if I understood correctly - if I `std::move`, it will probably `swap`, And I still need to call the d-tor or if I don't, there will be a leak. Is that correct?

Comment: @Nick, close enough. `std::move` does not destroy anything, it just casts an object to an rvalue reference, which (depending on what you do with it) might allow it to be the argument to a move constructor or move assignment operator.  But that still doesn't destroy anything, the object still exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can't move a live object, but you can move-construct another from it.

```
int main() {
    std::string str = "Hello World !";

    // Allocate some storage
    void *storage = std::malloc(sizeof str);

    std::cout << str << '\n';

    // Move-contruct the new string inside the storage
    std::string *str2 = new (storage) std::string(std::move(str));

    std::cout << str << '|' << *str2 << '\n';

    // Destruct the string and free the memory
    str2->~basic_string();
    free(storage);
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World !
|Hello World !
```